# Как в html css сделать строки из разных блоков на одном уровне по горизонтали?

Tags: html, css, html5

[image: Надо написать такой код, чтобы и в первом сером блоке, и во втором числа, идущие под "цена", "цена1" и "цена2", шли ровно под этими заголовками]

Надо написать такой код, чтобы и в первом сером блоке, и во втором числа, идущие под "цена", "цена1" и "цена2", шли ровно под этими заголовками

Comment: Покажите вашу разметку и стили, с которыми возникли сложности

Comment: В каком плане "под этими заголовками"? Они же и так центрированы

Answer (score 0):

в верстке "ровно" понятие довольно таки растяжимое.

```css
#a{text-align: left}
#b{text-align: right}
#c{text-align: center}
#d{text-align: justify}
```

```html
<p id='a'>ровно<br>по<br>левому<br>краю?</p>
<p id='b'>ровно<br>по<br>правому<br>краю?</p>
<p id='c'>ровно<br>по<br>центру<br>?</p>
<p id='d'>
быть может, ровно по обоим краям одновременно, при ощутимо разном колличестве символов у
названия столбца и значений в нем? пожалуй можно и так, правда нужный пробелы...
ssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss ssssssssssssssssss
ssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss ssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss</p>
```

ну это конечно при условии, что блоки стоят ровно друг над другом... вы ведь не показали свою верстку.